# How to delete the matched value from a column when matched with Char_length

Tags: mysql

Hi I am using the following sql query to select by length of the company column which works but i am stuck on how to empty/remove those matched column strings. I dont want to delete the row just remove the 1 character the below sql query matched.

```
select company FROM grocer_append WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(company) = 1
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm reading right, you just want to remove the character and have company be blank? This would work:

```
update grocer_append
    set company=''
    WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(company) = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Gordon Linoff. Sorry for the n00b question, but how do you do the grey box thing for code?

Comment: BryPie - just put 4 spaces before any line, or click the {} button after selecting your text.